# Liferay theme - html5

Tags: html, html5-canvas, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I am developing a portlet for Liferay (v6.0.5, runs on JBoss). I would like to use HTML5 (`canvas` to be more specific) in this portlet. How can I find, if the theme I am currently using on the portal does support HTML5?

I know that themes with HTML5 support exist and I have to choose the right one? Or am I wrong and all themes automatically support HTML5?

Thanks for tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the Liferay themes automatically support [html5](/questions/tagged/html5), its the browsers you should be worried about.

There is nothing special to make a theme HTML5 since its just a matter of [doctype](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp) change (`<!DOCTYPE html>`) to make the browser know that you are rendering HTML5 stuff. So you can check the doctype in `portal-normal.vm` and other template files to see if the theme is HTML5.

But for scripting support I doubt if [alloy-ui](/questions/tagged/alloy-ui) (Liferay's default library) provides any additional HTML5 specific modules for manipulating canvas, file-api etc.